# ExtJs lable not displying

Tags: javascript, extjs, label

I have a label initially which is hidden

```
var lblField = new Ext.form.LabelField({ xtype: 'label', text: 'This is lable text', hideLabel: true, hidden: true });
```

I am trying to make it visible by-

```
lblField.setVisible(true);
```

but the lable is not at all visible
what I am doing wrong here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this.

```
    var lblField = new Ext.form.Label( { 
        text: 'This is lable text',
        hidden: true, 
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });


   setTimeout(function(){ 
        lblField.setVisible(true);
   }, 2000);
```

I have created a fiddle for this.
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/tch

Comment: Sorry to update it late, I am using ExtJs 2.3 And Ext.create is not available there

Comment: I have updated my answer and fiddle to match with ExtJS2.3.

Comment: It is working perfectly fine in fiddle, whats wrong in my code

Comment: Class name in your code, Ext.form.LabelField, is wrong. Correct class name is Ext.form.Label.

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks a lot